# Get autocompletion when invoking a "read" inside a Bash script

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Inside my Bash script, I'm reading some variables entered by the user with `read`:

```
read -p "Glassfish Path:" GF_DIR
```

Now I want that the user gets a autocompletion when he has to enter a directory, like when you are on the Bash shell. So when he enters the first letters of a directory, he can autocomplete it by hitting TAB.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try:

```
read -e -p "Glassfish Path:" GF_DIR
```

`-e` [enables readline](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

```
 -e 
    If the standard input is coming from a terminal, Readline is used
    to obtain the line.
```

Comment: Sorry, should have read the manpage. Thought it's not that easy ;)

Comment: I've looked all over the interwebs, and taken many wrong turns with bash `complete`... yet it really was this easy the whole time. Thanks!

Comment: How do I get it to respect custom completions? That is, I have things set up so that, on the normal prompt, git branch names are completed. But when I use readline -e it's only completing file names.

Comment: @MaxHeiber Have never found a sane way to do that; though for some interactive scripts I create a temporary  directory with `mktemp --tmpdir -d foo.XXXXXXXX`, cd to it and touch files with the options, commands etc. I want to have completion on ... This then works nice with `-e`. Only have to be careful about being in correct directory when doing touch, rm etc ;)

Comment: @MaxHeiber Added an example of a different approach in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4819819/3342816#77567693). Created a generic function that generates the usual `COMP` variables, but have not worked out the quirks + the code is a mess/dev-stage. (I.e. works for my use, but is too ugly for public consumption).

Answer (score 0):

Native `readline` in bash-scripts only have the option to use the native completion.

If one want to add custom completion, one way is to use *mode* with *bind*.

It is a *"low level"* approach and one have to do more work like parsing input by for example splitting into words, find current word etc.

One can still use things like `compgen` and print options, modify the input line etc.

In short (rather naive example):

```bash
# Custom complete function
list=(foo bar baz)
comp() {
    # Here we have two variables that can be used to manipulate the read-line
    # 1) $READLINE_LINE:  The current line
    # 2) $READLINE_POINT: Position of cursor
    #
    # If either is changed in this function, it is reflected on the read-line
    #

    printf '%s ' "${list[@]}" >&2
    printf '\n' >&2
    printf 'I am inserting "foo "\n' >&2

    READLINE_LINE+="foo "
    (( READLINE_POINT += 4 ))
}
# Make it available to bind
export -f comp
# Enable readline mode
set -o emacs
# Bind TAB to our custom completion function
bind -x '"\t"':comp

while :; do
    # TAB pressed on read will now call "comp"
    read -rep"> " inp
    # process command
done
```