# Bash autocompletion in user input, Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I would like to setup a makefile that reads user input with Bash autocompletion, and based on that create a directory where some files would be copied into. Basically something like

```
$ make initializeProject
Enter destination: Dir<ectory>/Sub<directory>/ProjectDirectory

mkdir: created directory 'Directory/Subdirectory/ProjectDirectory'
'Templates/TemplateFile' -> 'Directory/Subdirectory/ProjectDirectory/TemplateFile'
```

where `< X >` stands for autocompleted parts.

As of now my makefile does not autocomplete, and it looks like this:

```
initProjectLaTeX:
        @read -p "Enter destination: " destination; \
        mkdir -pv $$destination; \
        cp -iv ~/.templates/latex/* $$destination
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819819/get-autocompletion-when-invoking-a-read-inside-a-bash-script) option, but it produces the error `/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -e`.
How can I access Bash autocompletion here?

Comment: It's really unusual for makefiles to be interactive like this. If you want to allow the user to provide parameters, it's usually done using command arguments.

Comment: @Barmar By command arguments, do you mean something like chepner's answer?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` uses `/bin/sh` as default shell and on many systems it's not the same as `bash` (e.g. on Debian is [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell)). I suspect that the `-e` option of `read` is a `bash` extension, that is why you get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -e
```

setting `/bin/bash` as the `SHELL` in the `Makefile` should work:

`Makefile`

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

initProjectLaTeX:
    @read -e -p "Enter destination: " destination; \
    mkdir -pv $$destination; \
    cp -iv ~/tmp/*c $$destination
```

example

```
$ make initProjectLaTeX
Enter destination: foo/bar/baz
mkdir: created directory 'foo'
mkdir: created directory 'foo/bar'
mkdir: created directory 'foo/bar/baz'
'/home/marco/tmp/foo.c' -> 'foo/bar/baz/foo.c'
$ tree foo
foo
└── bar
    └── baz
        └── foo.c

2 directories, 1 file
$
```

completion

```
$ make initProjectLaTeX
Enter destination: foo
foo/   foo.c
Enter destination: foo
foo/   foo.c
Enter destination: foo
```

Comment: Thank you! This did not seem to work when copying files, but now I understand more!

Comment: @aahlback that's strange, I updated my answer adding a copying example which worked smoothly, what error did you get?

Comment: Seems like the error was me. The code works great now and is what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have `make` interact with the user, pass the desired destination to `make`.

Start with a modified recipe:

```
initProjectLaTeX:
        mkdir -pn $(DESTINATION)
        cp -iv ~/.templates/latex/* $(DESTINATION)
```

then run

```
make initProjectLaTeX DESTINATION=Dir<ectory>/Sub<directory>/ProjectDirectory
```

(`bash` allows completion for the value of an assignment.)