# bash completion: description text when pressing TAB (sort of heredoc for autocompletion)

Tags: bash, autocomplete, completion

I created a beautiful autocompletion for my script.

One thing though: when the argument is left for the user to decide (for example, the first argument is the name of the new project), I'd like to **display a little line describing what is expected**.

```
For example:
$> script [TAB][TAB]
<name of project>
$> script my_new_project
```

.

Of course, I thought about this:

```
if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
        local IFS=$'\n'
        COMPREPLY+=($(compgen -W "<name of project>"))
```

The problem though is that I obtain this:

```
$> script [TAB][TAB]
$> script <name of project>
```

That is, the one text I defined is automatically added to the command line when I press TAB.

.

I also tried this:

```sh
local IFS=$':'
COMPREPLY+=($(compgen -W "Help: <domain name associated with the project>"))
```

But the result is garbled, and it still add the words to the command line:

```
$> script [TAB][TAB]
<domain name associated with the project> Help:
$> script <domain name associated with the project>
```

.

Please, do you know **if there's a sort of `heredoc` for autocompletion**, where a help text just appears, but is not added to the command line?

Thank you!

Comment: You may find [this approach](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/) useful. I haven't tried it out yet. But I also need the same effect you asked for.

Comment: Wow sometimes it's about patience ^^ Thank you for your comment, I'm going to have a look ASAP

Comment: I have updated the answer with a heredoc example.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `printf` wherever you need in the completion script. Here is what I would do:

```
if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
   printf "\n *** Enter a project name: %s" "${COMP_LINE[@]}"
fi
```

Printing the `COMP_LINE` array is not particularly useful for the first argument though. If you have many more arguments and want to show the user what they have typed in so far, printing `COMP_LINE` might be the way to do it.

Also, you might want to suggest the existing project names to the user. In that case:

```
if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
   printf "\n *** Enter a project name: %s" "${COMP_LINE[@]}"
   list_of_project_names=("project1" "theotherproject" "testproject")
   COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${list_of_project_names[@]}" -- "$2"))
fi
```

Note that in a completion script, `$2` is the current word being completed, `$3` is the previous word, and `$1` is the first word in the current command line.

For much longer descriptions, you can use '[heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/6474744)':

```
if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
  cat<<EOF
# leave a blank line for formatting

*** You can select a project from suggestions or enter a
*** name for your new project:
EOF
  # Use _printf_ for printing the "${COMP_LINE[@]}" because
  # the _heredoc_ adds a newline to the end.
  printf ">>> %s" "${COMP_LINE[@]}"
  list_of_project_names=("project1" "theotherproject" "testproject")
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${list_of_project_names[@]}" -- "$2"))
fi
```

You can also use the `read` command with `-e` option as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819945/6474744

For more complex behavior, you might find this interesting https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/

Cheers